# Find the equation of the normal at a point

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

Find the equation of the normal at the point $(2, 1)$ for the function $x^2 + y^3 - 2y = 3$

I'm still struggling a bit with the application of derivatives, but from what I understand I use the derivative to calculate the slope

\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx}x^2 + y^3 - 2y &= \frac{dy}{dx} 3\\
(3y^2 - 2)\frac{dy}{dx} &= 0 - 2x\\
\frac{dy}{dx} &= \frac{-2x}{(3y^2 - 2)}
\end{align}

I then plug the values of the point to get the slope
$m = \frac{-2(2)}{(3(1)^2 - 2)} = \frac{-4}{1} = -4$

I then plug all of this into the equation $y - 1 = -4 (x + 2)$

Is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything looks good, except when you use $m = -4$ in the equation of the desired line: What you post in the end is the equation of the line *tangent* to the curve at $(2, 1)$.

The slope of the *normal* is the negative reciprocal of $-4$: $\dfrac 14$.

That gives us $$y - 1 = \frac 14(x - 2)$$

Comment: Crumbs... that's right, I better remember that come exam time.

Comment: The slope should be $\frac{1}{4}$, and it should be $y-1=\frac{1}{4}(x-2)$...

Comment: I caught that, just as you "spoke", @stochasm. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I was wondering, you edited it almost immediately after I clicked "Add Comment". I was like "wow...this dude is fast..."